# If $i(x,z)\neq 0$ and if $y$ is conjugate of $x$, then what can we say about $i(x*y,z)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

Let $S_g$ denote the closed oriented surface of genus $g\geq 2$. Let $x,y$ be two different (upto fixed base point  homotopy) but freely homotopic curves, i.e. $y$ is a non-trivial element from a fixed conjugacy class of $x$. If there exist a simple closed loop $z$ (non-trivial) with $i(x,z)\neq 0$ , where $i(\ , \ )$ denotes the geometric intersection number. Then is it true that $i(x*y,z)\neq 0$?

One can prove that if $y=x$ (upto fixed base point homotopy) , then $i(x,z)\neq 0$ implies $i(x^2,z)\neq 0$ , because the hyperbolic axis correspond to the translation $[x],[x^2]\in \pi_1(S_g)$ in $\mathbb H^2$ are same. Also the reason I've chosen $z$ to be a simple closed loop, becasue I think $x*y$ cannot be a simple closed loop here.

I'm unable to find some proof/counter-example. Although my intuition says that it should be true but I would be happy if some one give me a counter-example with a good (general) explanation.

Comment: I could not able to think about a suitable title. So please feel free to edit the title.

Comment: What does $x\ast y$ mean?

Comment: @Sanath https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group#Definition

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought you meant something else.

Comment: This question is closely related to this one: http://mathoverflow.net/q/258189/1345

Comment: @IanAgol I have posted a counter example, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is simple, then this is true. Here is an outline of the proof.

1) As $x$ and $y$ are freely homotopic, $y=x^g$ for some $g$. As $x$ is simple, $A_x$ and $A_y$ are disjoint.

2) Consider the Theorem 7.38.3  of Beardon's "Geometry of discrete group." Observe that $g$ is the common perpendicular, therefore $\epsilon =+1$.

3) This implies if length of $x$ increases, so does length of $x*y$ (in Teichnuller space).

4) Take right twists along the curve $z$. This will increase the length of $x$ (as $i(x,z)\neq 0$) and hence must increase the length of $x*y$ which implies $i(x*y,z)\neq=0$.

As long as $A_x$ and $A_y$ are disjoint, this proof will work. The other case is when $A_x\cap A_y\neq \emptyset.$ Then $x$ is not simple and their product formula is given by Theorem 7.38.3  of Beardon's "Geometry of discrete group," where $v_2$ will be a lift of the self-intersection point. Now there are two cases:

1) If $cos\theta$ is positive at $v_2$ then the above arguments hold true.

2) If $cos\theta$ is negative, it is the same question as [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258189/geometric-intersection-number-for-product-of-elements-of-the-fundamental-group?noredirect=1&lq=1)mentioned by Ian Agol for the following reason. Take the self intersection point and consider the two branches of the curves starting and ending at this intersection point. Name them $x$ and $y$. If $y$ is a power of $x$ then you are done by your observation. If not then you get the case $n=1$ of the above question.

Comment: I think you have made some mistake. I've posted a coubter example. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is a counter exampleb of my question. (proposed by Dan Margalit)

Comment: What is the curve $z$ in your pic?

Comment: Take a curve in the 3 rd hole away from one curve

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused. If you take the third hole (from left) and consider any curve around it as $z$ then $i(x,z)=0$.

Comment: @cusp take something transversal to the loop. And that own intersect $y$ .

Comment: Any loop in and around the third hole has geometric intersection number 0 with $x$ and hence with $y$. It would be helpful if you update the pic with more details.

Comment: Yeah, I can see now.

Comment: @cusps this example says that some curve has intersection 0 with two curves x and y but not with x*y.

Comment: @anubhab That's correct, but your question is different.

Comment: Yeah, and now I realized that ... :P I'll edit my and as soon as I reach my place.